# ftrace + addr2line on raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, kernel, raspberry-pi3

I want to get kernel source code file name and line number of a kernel function from the function address that ftrace outputed on rapberry pi 3.

I tried `addr2line -e /boot/kernel8.img [function address]` on raspberry pi 3. But it returned `addr2line: /boot/kernel8.img: File format not recognized`.

note:

`kernel8.img` is customed kernel that i compiled. I cloned kernel source from `https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git`, checkouted to `rpi-4.18.y`, turned on `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`, and run `make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -j4`. This compile work performed on ubuntu x86_64 linux kernel 4.15.0-23-generic. The type of kernel8.img is as follows.

```
$ file kernel8.img
kernel8.img: MS-DOS executable
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe research over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ This is way too Pi specific to be a general programming Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `addr2line` against the `vmlinux` file (i.e. uncompressed/raw kernel binary). `/boot/kernel8.img` is, most probably, a `zImage` (i.e. compressed kernel).
You can find the `vmlinux` file in the root of your kernel sources after compilation.